# old sequelize migration did not run, how to re run it

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js, migration, command-line-interface

I have a database with is interfaced through sequelize. I have multiple environments, and for some reason a specific migration did not run on production, but seemingly went trough as expected on our development, staging and test databases. Since then, multiple migrations has been run. Is it possible to safely rerun a specific migration after it is recognized as having been run?

The migration name is `20210316102540-delete_clothes_columns_expired_in_webshop_and_in_store.js`

The migration has no `down` function, so maybe I would be able to `db:migrate:undo --name 20210316102540-delete_clothes_columns_expired_in_webshop_and_in_store.js` and `db:migrate` after? Is that a safe approach?

`20210316102540-delete_clothes_columns_expired_in_webshop_and_in_store.js`

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {
    await queryInterface.sequelize.query(`UPDATE clothes SET status = 'ACTIVE' WHERE in_store = TRUE AND status = 'IDLE';`, {transaction: t})
    await queryInterface.removeColumn('clothes', 'in_webshop', {transaction: t})
    await queryInterface.removeColumn('clothes', 'expired', {transaction: t})
    await queryInterface.removeColumn('clothes', 'in_store', {transaction: t})
    })
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    /**
     * Add reverting commands here.
     *
     * Example:
     * await queryInterface.dropTable('users');
     */
  }
};
```

To make sure it has been run

```
production=# select * from "SequelizeMeta";
                                          name                                           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ...
 20210316102540-delete_clothes_columns_expired_in_webshop_and_in_store.js
 ...
(11 rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure why the migration had not run. But I ended up deleting the row in SequelizeMeta and rerunning it.

`delete from "SequelizeMeta" where name = '20210316102540-delete_clothes_columns_expired_in_webshop_and_in_store.js';`

`sequelize-cli db:migrate`

Comment: This also works for me: `npm run sequelize -- db:migrate:undo --env <your env>`